# Woocommerce wp dashboard access

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Thanks in advance for your great help.

Woocommerce doesn't allow my users to access the WP dashboard, it just redirect them to "my-account" page. I have tried using different techniques but none of them worked. If you have any idea of this could be achieved, please answer this question. What i want is the following.

1 - I want my custom user role "teamadmin" to have access to wordpress dashboard. That's it.

The only problem is that woocommerce doesn't allow users to access wp dashbaord.

Best Regards, 
Abbas

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to use [Remove Dashboard access](https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-dashboard-access-for-non-admins/) plugin to do what you want to do.

The plugin allows you to choose user roles that can get access to the dashboard. You'll choose customers.